# md5 hash value change

Tags: hash, md5

I have generated hash values for files using md5. If there is any change in the file the hash value changes. Does it also change when the file permismsions get modified?

Comment: It depends. Did you include the file permissions in the data you hashed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The MD5 hash of a file is related to its content, not its permissions.

Comment: I don't think there's really such a thing as the "MD5 hash of a file". The MD5 hash of a file's content is related to its content. But the MD5 hash of its permissions would relate to its permissions. If a file includes its permissions, then the MD5 hash of "a file" would relate to its permissions and its content.

Comment: If the file includes its permissions, the permissions are actually part of the content.

Comment: i am using this bash script "digest -a md5 -v /filename" which generates a hash value, which changes on modification of the file.

Comment: What is "digest"? Is that some program? What does its documentation say it does? Does it say it hashes the files data contents? Or its metadata? Or both? Or what?

Comment: here u can have a look.  http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.aix.cmds%2Fdoc%2Faixcmds2%2Fdigest.htm

Comment: @user1212207: I think that's the wrong `digest` command. This `digest` is an internal part of qdaemon and has nothing to do with MD5.

Answer (score 0):

The MD5 hash will change if there's any change to whatever data you input to the MD5 hashing function. If you fed it the permissions and the permission change, then the MD5 hash will change. If you fed it only the contents, then the MD5 hash will change only if the contents change.

What you get out depends on what you put in. You haven't told us what you put in. So we can't tell you what the output depends on.

Comment: I checked the Solaris `digest` command, which seems to have the syntax you are using. It processes only the file's data contents and ignores all metadata such as filename, permissions, and the like.